# zulip mailgun: 5.7.0 Mailgun is not loving your login or password

Tags: smtp, mailgun, zulip

I have tried to set up a Zulip server. For now it works but I can not invite anbybody, actually, the smtp server doesn't work. 
I use mailgun, here is its configuration:

then for my Zulip configuration, I set up:

- /etc/zulip/setting.py

> EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailgun.org' EMAIL_HOST_USER =
>   'postmaster@www2.vt*****'
>
> MAIL_USERNAME = 'testsmtp@www2.vt******' 
>   MAIL_PASSWORD = 'Az******'
>   SECURITY_EMAIL_SENDER = 'testsmtp@www2.vt******'
>
> EMAIL_USE_TLS = True EMAIL_PORT = 587

- /etc/zulip/zulip-secrets.conf

  [secrets] 
  zulip_org_id = 9724f205-ed93-4******** 
  mail_password = 12****** 
  postgres_password = ******* 
  email_password = cw4DKsfuHnJ********* (password for my account postmaster@www2.vt*****)

Even though, when I try the command: /home/zulip/deployments/current/manage.py send_test_email testsmtpsend@laposte.net I get the error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 720, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 641, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.0 Mailgun is not loving your login or password')
```

Someone knows where this error could come from ? It seems my login or password isn't good but I tried every account I had on mailgun, I even tried to create new ones...